# installing Win32::OLE on mac os x

Tags: perl, ole, cpan, win32ole

Mac OS X supports Microsoft OLE.

Does anyone know if it's possible to install the Win32::OLE perl module on mac OS X?

I know the module isn't supported on Mac, but would it be possible to try and compile anyway?

Comment: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.13/13.06/ActiveXControlsforMac/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so that Mac Os X supports Microsoft OLE nativly. I think, it is some kind emulating or something like that.

Win32* modules checks the osversion ($^O if I am correct) to detect which os is run.

With force and without tests you could install this module but I think is won't work after install.

If you have an evidence that Mac OS X supports MS OLE please link that article into your question and you could ask the module maintainer to support OSX if it is really support OLE.

regards,

Comment: I added a comment in the answer with the link to one article about Active X (it uses OLE) for Mac OS X, but currently the links to the SDK are broken.

Answer (score 1):

Modules in the [Win32::](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Win32%3A%3A) namespace, are for modules that work directly with Windows.

This means that it won't work on anything that doesn't present itself as Windows.

You could use a Win32 build of Perl running under [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/). Note that this would only be able to work with Windows versions of a program that are also running under [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/). (Assuming you can get it to work at all.)